# JAVA -BigDecimal randomly between 0.00 to 1000.00

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need method which will generate a big decimal numbers between 0.00 to 1000.00. anyone can help? In google i can find only between 0-1 or something else... but this doesn't help me
Thank You!

Comment: What is the precision required?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Random from 0 till 100000 then result divide by 100. Now try to implement it and if you will have problems with code ask more specific question.

Comment: where is your code so far?

Comment: why not take the 0-1 method, and multiply it with 1000?

Comment: @bali182 It sounds like he wants a number with two decimal places.  In that case, take a number from 0-1, multiply by 100000, use `floor`, then divide by 100.

Comment: I need a money- between 0.00 euro to 1000.00 - generate randomly numbers like:
1.12, 987.23, 784.23, 78.19

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new BigDecimal(BigInteger.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(100001)), 2)
```

Generates an integer uniformly at random between 0 and 10,000 inclusive, and creates a BigDecimal with that value divided by 100.

Comment: great! i added one zero in nextInt method and it works! god bless You :-)